# "Differential Operator" Over Polynomial Space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, differential-operators

Let's suppose we are given the differential operator
$T \colon \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{C})$, over the space of quadratic polynomials with complex coefficients, such that $T(p(t)) := p(t) + t^2\,p'(t)$, and we are asked to find it's kernel. Of course, setting $p(t) := a_0 + a_1\,t + a_2\,t^2$, where $a_0,\,a_1,\,a_2 \in \mathbb{C}$, one can easily find that $\text{Ker}(T) = \left\{0\right\}$, the zero polynomial, with the polynomial equality. 
But, can we actualy solve the equation $p(t) + t^2\,p'(t) = 0$? I know we're going to find an exponential solution of the form $k\exp(1/t)$, but can we take $k = 0$ (and hence $p(t) = 0$) to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the equation is a homogeneous linear ODE  for $p$. All such ODEs have 0 as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from $p(t) + t^2\,p'(t) = 0$ it necessarily follows that
$$p(t) = ke^{1/t}$$
for some $k\in\Bbb{R}$. However, the $n$-th derivative of $p$ can be calculated inductively as
$$p^{(n)}(t) = ke^{1/t}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{(-1)^j j!}{t^{j+1}} \implies p^{(n)}(1) = k \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^jj!$$
Since $p$ is a polynomial, for large enough $n \in \Bbb{N}$ we should have $p^{(n)}(1) = 0$ but we don't even have $\lim_{n\to\infty} p^{(n)}(1) = 0$ unless $k=0$. Hence $p=0$.

---

There is also a simpler solution using degree. Assume there is a $p \ne 0$ satisfying $p(t) + t^2\,p'(t) = 0$. Clearly $p$ cannot be constant so $\deg p \ge 1$. From $p(t) = -t^2p'(t)$ we get
$$\deg p = 2+\deg p' = 2+(\deg p - 1) = \deg p + 1$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks very much!